# JDBC Error. Help me

Tags: jdbc

I'm making reservation program.

I face MySQL JDBC Error.

I executed code below.

```
public void ReservationModifyQuery(String room, String name, String phone, String nop, String revdate, String revtime, String usetime, String isgroup, String id, String PrefRoom, String PrefReservationTime, String PrefDateString, Connection conn) throws Exception{

    String updateDB = "UPDATE reservation SET ";
    String sql =    "roomNum = ?,"+
                    "Name = ? ,"+
                    "Phone = ? ,"+
                    "NumOfPeople = ? ,"+
                    "ReservationDate = ? ,"+
                    "ReservationTime = ? ,"+
                    "UseTime = ? ,"+
                    "Group = ? ,"+
                    "ID = ? ";

    sql = "roomNum = ?";
    String where = "where roomNum = ? and ReservationDate = ? and ReservationTime = ? ;";
    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(updateDB+sql+where);
    pstmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(room));
    pstmt.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(PrefRoom));
    pstmt.setDate(3, Date.valueOf(PrefDateString));
    pstmt.setTime(4, Time.valueOf(PrefReservationTime));
    pstmt.executeUpdate();

    sql = "Name = ?";
    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(updateDB+sql+where);
    pstmt.setString(1, name);
    pstmt.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(PrefRoom));
    pstmt.setDate(3, Date.valueOf(PrefDateString));
    pstmt.setTime(4, Time.valueOf(PrefReservationTime));
    pstmt.executeUpdate();

    sql = "Phone = ?";
    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(updateDB+sql+where);
    pstmt.setString(1, phone);
    pstmt.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(PrefRoom));
    pstmt.setDate(3, Date.valueOf(PrefDateString));
    pstmt.setTime(4, Time.valueOf(PrefReservationTime));
    pstmt.executeUpdate();

    sql = "NumOfPeople = ?";
    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(updateDB+sql+where);
    pstmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(nop));
    pstmt.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(PrefRoom));
    pstmt.setDate(3, Date.valueOf(PrefDateString));
    pstmt.setTime(4, Time.valueOf(PrefReservationTime));
    pstmt.executeUpdate();

    sql = "ReservationDate = ?";
    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(updateDB+sql+where);
    pstmt.setDate(1, Date.valueOf(revdate));
    pstmt.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(PrefRoom));
    pstmt.setDate(3, Date.valueOf(PrefDateString));
    pstmt.setTime(4, Time.valueOf(PrefReservationTime));
    pstmt.executeUpdate();

    sql = "ReservationTime = ?";
    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(updateDB+sql+where);
    pstmt.setTime(1, Time.valueOf(revtime));
    pstmt.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(PrefRoom));
    pstmt.setDate(3, Date.valueOf(PrefDateString));
    pstmt.setTime(4, Time.valueOf(PrefReservationTime));
    pstmt.executeUpdate();

    sql = "UseTime = ?";
    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(updateDB+sql+where);
    pstmt.setDouble(1, Double.parseDouble(usetime));
    pstmt.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(PrefRoom));
    pstmt.setDate(3, Date.valueOf(PrefDateString));
    pstmt.setTime(4, Time.valueOf(PrefReservationTime));
    pstmt.executeUpdate();

    sql = "Group = ?";
    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(updateDB+sql+where);
    pstmt.setString(1, isgroup);
    pstmt.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(PrefRoom));
    pstmt.setDate(3, Date.valueOf(PrefDateString));
    pstmt.setTime(4, Time.valueOf(PrefReservationTime));
    pstmt.executeUpdate();

    sql = "ID = ?";
    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(updateDB+sql+where);
    pstmt.setString(1, id);
    pstmt.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(PrefRoom));
    pstmt.setDate(3, Date.valueOf(PrefDateString));
    pstmt.setTime(4, Time.valueOf(PrefReservationTime));
    pstmt.executeUpdate();


    pstmt.close();
    conn.close();
}
```

This code occurs Syntax Exception below.
but I don't know error section...

[image]

How can I solve this matter?

Comment: You make two assignments to the `sql` variable in the beginning. Is this what you really want to do?

Comment: Please include the full stacktrace as **text** in your question, do not use images for things that can be conveyed by text. BTW: The problem is probably the missing space between `?` and `WHERE` after concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no space between your statements. In your code, SQL for preparedStatement is

```
UPDATE reservation SET roomNum=?,Name = ?,Phone = ? ,NumOfPeople = ? ,ReservationDate = ? ,ReservationTime = ? ,UseTime = ? ,Group = ? ,ID = ?where roomNum = ? and ReservationDate = ? and ReservationTime = ? ;
```

which is not correct because there is no space between ? and where.

I have also removed semi-colon from where statement. Use

```
String where = " where roomNum = ? and ReservationDate = ? and ReservationTime = ? ";
```

instead of

```
String where = "where roomNum = ? and ReservationDate = ? and ReservationTime = ? ;";
```